# Reverse for 'detalle_reserva' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reserva/(?P<reserva_id>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, view, django-urls

Please help me, I don't know why I get this error, I'm following a youtube tutorial and I don't understand why the error.

i try changing the path in urls but it didn't work.

I was looking for more solutions to the same problem and none of them work.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Reserva(models.Model):
    auto = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fecha_reserva = models.DateField(null=True)

    hora1 = '9:00am - 10:00am'
    hora2 = '10:00am - 11:00am'
    hora3 = '11:00am - 12:00pm'
    hora4 = '12:00pm - 13:00pm'
    hora5 = '14:00pm - 15:00pm'
    hora6 = '15:00pm - 16:00pm'
    hora7 = '16:00pm - 17:00pm'
    hora8 = '17:00pm - 18:00pm'
    hora_reserva_CHOICES = [
        (hora1, '9:00am - 10:00am'),
        (hora2, '10:00am - 11:00am'),
        (hora3, '11:00am - 12:00pm'),
        (hora4, '12:00pm - 13:00pm'),
        (hora5, '14:00pm - 15:00pm'),
        (hora6, '15:00pm - 16:00pm'),
        (hora7, '16:00pm - 17:00pm'),
        (hora8, '17:00pm - 18:00pm')
    ]
    hora_reserva = models.CharField(
        max_length=17,
        choices=hora_reserva_CHOICES,
        default=hora1
    )

    Mantención = 'Mantención'
    Reparación = 'Reparación'
    Limpieza = 'Limpieza'
    Servicios_CHOICES = [
        (Mantención, 'Mantención'),
        (Reparación, 'Reparación'),
        (Limpieza, 'Limpieza'),
    ]
    Servicios = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=Servicios_CHOICES,
        default=Limpieza,
    )

    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.auto + ' -by ' + self.User.username
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Main import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('reserva/', views.reserva, name='reserva'),
    path('reserva/crear/', views.crearreserva, name='crearreserva'),
    path('reserva/<reserva_id>/',
         views.detalle_reserva, name='detalle_reserva'),
    path('logout/', views.logouto, name='logout'),
    path('login/', views.logino, name='login')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from .forms import ReservaForm
from .models import Reserva

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Home.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'SignUp.html', {
            'form': UserCreationForm
        })

    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'],
                                                password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('reserva')
            except:
                return render(request, 'SignUp.html', {
                    'form': UserCreationForm,
                    "error": 'Usuario ya existente'
                })
        return render(request, 'SignUp.html', {
            'form': UserCreationForm,
            "error": 'Contraseña no coinside'
        })


def reserva(request):
    todas = Reserva.objects.filter(User=request.user)
    return render(request, 'Reserva.html', {'todas': todas})


def crearreserva(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'CrearReserva.html', {
            'form': ReservaForm
        })
    else:
        try:
            form = ReservaForm(request.POST)
            nueva_reserva = form.save(commit=False)
            nueva_reserva.User = request.user
            nueva_reserva.save()
            return redirect('reserva')
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'CrearReserva.html', {
                'form': ReservaForm,
                'error': 'Ingrese datos validos porfavor'
            })


def detalle_reserva(request, reserva_id):
    reserva = Reserva.objects.get(pk=reserva_id)
    return render(request, 'DetalleReserva.html', {
        'reserva': reserva
    })


def logouto(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')


def logino(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'LogIn.html', {
            'form': AuthenticationForm
        })
    else:
        user = authenticate(
            request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is None:
            return render(request, 'LogIn.html', {
                'form': AuthenticationForm,
                'error': 'Usuario o Contraseña erroneas'
            })
        else:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('reserva')
```

html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ServiExpress</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/css.css' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Menú-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="{% static '/img/logo3.png' %}" alt="logo" width="300px">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <!--Home-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <!--Servicios-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Servicios</a>
                </li>
                <!--Reserva-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/reserva">Reserva</a>
                </li>
                <!--Quienes somos-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">¿Quienes somos?</a>
                </li>
                <!--Contacto-->
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--Inicio sesión-->
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" onclick="location.href='/logout'">Cerrar sesión</button>
            {% else %}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" onclick="location.href= '/login'">Iniciar
                sesión</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" onclick="location.href= '/signup'">Crear
                usuario</button>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>
    <ul>
        {% for Reserva in todas %}
        <a href="{%  url 'detalle_reserva' reserva.id %}">
            <li>
                <h1>{{Reserva.auto}}</h1>
                <p>{{Reserva.Servicios}}</p>
                <p>{{Reserva.fecha_reserva}}</p>
                <p>{{Reserva.hora_reserva}}</p>
            </li>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much for helping me with my stupid problem

Comment: You have a capital letter in {% for Reserva in todas %} at the bottom of your template, but no capital letter in the reserva.id below it, so the ID isn't being found.

Comment: Yes, there are a few places where you are using casing incorrectly. Replace `Mantención = 'Mantención'` with `MANTENCION = 'Mantención'`. Replace `{% for Reserva in todas %}` with `{% for reserva in todas %}`. Replace `todas = Reserva.objects.filter(User=request.user)` with `todas = Reserva.objects.filter(user=request.user)` etc.

Comment: In short: Capitalised class names; lowercase for variable names, ALL_UPPERCASE for constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be correction for id of Reserva `url` like this...

```py
    {% for Reserva in todas %}
            <a href="{%  url 'detalle_reserva' Reserva.id %}">
                <li>
                    <h1>{{Reserva.auto}}</h1>
                    <p>{{Reserva.Servicios}}</p>
                    <p>{{Reserva.fecha_reserva}}</p>
                    <p>{{Reserva.hora_reserva}}</p>
                </li>
            </a>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: wow it works perfect, thank you very much for fixing my stupid mistake